# Python syntax error in seeming properly formatted code

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error in my code at `elif not running:` but I don't understand why. Everything seems to be formatted correctly, but yet I still get that syntax error.

```
running = True
def checker():
    global running
    if running:
        if label.image == colorPhoto:
            label.image = blackPhoto
            label.configure(image = blackPhoto)
            #GPIO.output(16,True)
            #root.after(2000,checker)
        elif label.image == blackPhoto:
            label.image = colorPhoto
            label.configure(image = colorPhoto
            #GPIO.output(16,False)
            #root.after(2000,checker)
    elif not running:
        label.image = colorPhoto
        label.configure(image = colorPhoto)
        #GPIO.output(16,False)
def press():
    global running
    if not running:
        running = True
        checker()
    if running:
        running = False
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on `label.configure(image = colorPhoto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a closing bracket at label.configure(image = colorPhoto